# Eventfilter on MapCanvas

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I'm trying to capture MouseClick events on the QgsMapCanvas. The goal is to intercept the right mouse button and display a custom context menu.
If the right mouse button is pressed with a modifier key (SHIFT+CTRL for example), the active tool action should be triggered.

I tried to install an event filter on the QgsMapCanvas provided by the iface, but this is not working.

```
class MyPlugin:
    def __init__(self, iface: QgisInterface):
        self.iface = iface
        self.eventFilter: MyEventFilter = None

    def initGui(self):
        self.registerEventFilter()

    def unload(self):
        self.unregisterEventFilter()

    def registerEventFilter(self):
        if not self.eventFilter:
            self.eventFilter = MyEventFilter(self.iface.mapCanvas())
        self.iface.mapCanvas().installEventFilter(self.eventFilter)

    def unregisterEventFilter(self):
        if self.eventFilter:
            self.eventFilter.deleteLater()
            self.eventFilter = None
```

and the EventHandler looks like this:

```
class MyEventFilter(QObject):

    def __init__(self, parent: Optional[QObject] = None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)

    def eventFilter(self, caller: QObject, event: QEvent) -> bool:
        if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
            QMessageBox.information(None, 'MyEventFilter', f'event: {event}')
            return True
        return False
```

But when I click, nothing happens. I guess the active tool itself is already filtering the click?

I've seen that QgsMapCanvas has signals for the mouse position as well as keypresses, but unfortunately no mouse click signals.

I know that you can implement a map tool, but the idea is to have a global contextmenu handler that is always called first. Only with a modifier key the original tool action should be triggered.

Is there any mechanism to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the event filter on the canvas' `viewport`. Event filters do not work as expected with mouse events on classes derived from `QAbstractScrollArea` (`QgsMapCanvas`, `QGraphicsView`, `QTextEdit`, etc...)

Replace your code with the following, and it should work.

```
class MyPlugin:
    def __init__(self, iface: QgisInterface):
        self.iface = iface
        self.eventFilter: MyEventFilter = None

    def initGui(self):
        self.registerEventFilter()

    def unload(self):
        self.unregisterEventFilter()

    def registerEventFilter(self):
        if not self.eventFilter:
            self.eventFilter = MyEventFilter(self.iface.mapCanvas())
        self.iface.mapCanvas().viewport().installEventFilter(self.eventFilter)

    def unregisterEventFilter(self):
        if self.eventFilter:
            self.iface.mapCanvas().viewport().removeEventFilter(self.eventFilter)
            self.eventFilter.deleteLater()
```